# How work with different classes from 1 interface (class)

Tags: php, oop

i have a problem.

For example: i have class "Provider" and sub classes "Provider_1", "Provider_2".

"Provider" - manager for "Provider_1" and "Provider_2".

how it works now:

1. i have a method getFullInfo() in "Provider", "Provider_1" and "Provider_2" classes.
2. i want get info from Provider_1::getFullInfo(), but my controller must work through "Provider" class.

I do request: Provider::getFullInfo($provider_id) and in Provider::getFullInfo use switch..case construction for routing.

My question: how make request from through "Provider" without switch..case construction.

Thanks

Comment: Show your actual code, are you using static methods as your `::` indicates?

Comment: Do the classes `provider_1` and `provider_2` inherit `provider`? If so you just can call `getFullInfo`without having to know if its a `prodiver`, `provider_1` or `provider_X`

Comment: @DarkBee you can take link to example?

Comment: @JuanMendes it not require. i can use non-static classes.

Comment: You are asking a question about **your code** without showing us **your code**. Doesn't that seem silly to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example to eloborate on my comment. As you can see, if u extend all from the same interface/class you can just call the method without testing the actual type as long as you know its of the `super` type Foo, in this case

```
<?php

class Foo {
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($n) {
        $this->name = $n;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

}

class FooBar extends Foo {
    public function getName() {
        return strtoupper($this->name);
    }
}

function sayName(Foo $f) {
    return 'Hello '. $f->getName();
}

$instances = array(
    new Foo('Foo'),
    new Bar('Bar'),
    new FooBar('FooBar'),
);

foreach($instances as $instance) {
    echo sayName($instance).'<br />'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are overriding the parent method getFullInfo() in your child classes.
2. if you want to user the parent method you have to use the parent class (provider), or, using the child class (provider_1), call from within its method the parent method

   function getFullInfo() {parent::getFullInfo(); ... }

This way you can use a child object but using the parent method.

I'm not sure if I understood correctly what you are trying to accomplish though.